# How to load test Nami with Vesting example?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nami

I'm working through week3 of PPP#4:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8TuGSzhqXU&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2zXSjHRKLSc5Jn9vJFA3_O&index=5]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8TuGSzhqXU&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2zXSjHRKLSc5Jn9vJFA3_O&index=5%5D)

Here, the Vesting example using Lucid is demo and while I'm able to load the dApp on my browser with `npm start` and I have a Nami wallet connected to the Preview network, its info/ PubKeyHash is failing to populate dApp like in the video. I'm not sure how to get the dApp to link with the browser wallet to create example transactions locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the instructor's old API key instead of creating one for myself through blockfrost. I just had to modify the section:

```
async function loadCardano() {
    const nami = window.cardano.nami;
    if (!nami) {
        setTimeout(loadCardano);
    } else {
        const api = await nami.enable();
        console.log('nami enabled');
        const lucid = await L.Lucid.new(
            new L.Blockfrost("https://cardano-preview.blockfrost.io/api/v0", "XXXX"),
            "Preview",
        );
        console.log('lucid active');
        lucid.selectWallet(api);
        return lucid;
    }
}
```